# Overriding Default.xml removes Sign In link from header - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2

I'm building a theme off the back of Luma. I'm mainly doing a few colour changes and moving a few elements around.

When I override the following, it removes the '**Sign In**' link from the header:

**Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

Another weird behaviour is:

If I take out my **overriding default.xml**, redeploy the website (flush the cache etc), the link comes back, then when I put my default.xml back in and redeploy, the link stays until I flush the cache, it then disappears.

Comment: Do not override whole Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml in your theme. just put which content you want to change

Comment: @hweb87 Thank you, for the changes I want, is this OK? https://paste.ee/p/ZqIaY#s=0 - It is just moving 2 elements around.

Comment: Yes, Perfect, It's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not override whole `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` in your theme. just put which content you want to change